# Difficulty with Django Rest Framework (DRF) Swagger Authentication Configuration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I'm encountering issues configuring authentication for the Swagger in the Django Rest Framework. I've set up the `drf_yasg` package along with the necessary configurations in settings.py and urls.py. However, when I try to log out using Swagger, I get a 403 Forbidden error, and subsequent attempts to access Swagger result in a blank page.

settings.py:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'basic': {
            'type': 'basic'
        }
    },
    'LOGIN_URL': 'rest_framework:login',  # Configuring login URL for Swagger
    'LOGOUT_URL': 'rest_framework:logout',  # Configuring logout URL for Swagger
}

REDOC_SETTINGS = {
    'LAZY_RENDERING': False,
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from rest_framework import permissions

API_TITLE = "Blog API"
API_DESCRIPTION = "A Web API for creating and editing blog posts."

# Configuration for drf-yasg
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title=API_TITLE,
        default_version='v1',
        description=API_DESCRIPTION,
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated],  # Setting permission for the schema_view
)

urlpatterns = [
    # Routes for admin views and API
    # ... (other routes)

    # Routes for Swagger UI documentation in different formats
    path('swagger<format>/', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),

    # Route for ReDoc documentation
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]
```

I've configured the `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGOUT_URL` in `SWAGGER_SETTINGS` and used `permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]` for the `schema_view`. Despite this, the logout from Swagger results in a 403 Forbidden error and subsequent issues. Any insights on what might be causing this and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

I appreciate any help you can provide.